# GCH implies that $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If GCH holds, then
$ 2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$  for all $\kappa$

It is true that $2^{<\kappa}=\sup_{\delta <\kappa}(2^\delta)$

some explain this for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you meant to write $2^\delta$ in that second line.

Answer (score 5):

The definition of $2^{<\kappa}$ is $\sup\{2^\lambda\mid\lambda<\kappa\}$.

If $\sf GCH$ holds then $2^\lambda=\lambda^+$.

- If $\kappa=\lambda^+$ then $2^{<\kappa}$ is really just $2^\lambda=\lambda^+ = \kappa$.
- If $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal, then $\lambda<\kappa$ implies $2^\lambda=\lambda^+<\kappa$, therefore $\sup\{\lambda^+\mid\lambda<\kappa\}=\kappa$.

Comment: hmmm, nice, thanks for you two, especially Asaf

Comment: I hope I didn't make too radical an edit to your answer.  I know how you feel about such things.  :-)

Comment: @Arthur: It's fine. That's a minor typo, not an additional expansion. :-)